# Not getting function parameters passed from asm to C via registers with __attribute__((fastcall))

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I'm trying to call C functions from assembler but I'm not getting the values (parameters) passed as expected.

The fastcall attribute generates a warning from gcc and is ignored!

I'm using MASM style coding and compiling that with jwasm (or uasm).

```
jwasm -q -10 -elf64 -mf -zf0 asmfunc.asm -Fo asmfunc.o
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((fastcall)) void DumpRCX(unsigned long long rcx)
{
    printf("%llx\n", rcx);
}

void asmfunc(void);

main(arc, *argv[])
{
    asmfunc();
}
```

asmfunc.asm

```
EXTERN  DumpRCX: PROC

PUBLIC asmfunc
asmfunc PROC
    sub rsp, 28h
    mov rcx, 84h ; any value for testing
    call DumpRCX
    add rsp, 28h
    ret
asmfunc ENDP
```

It runs and enters the DumpRCX function but the value in RCX is never 84h.

My understanding is that fastcall should pass the first argument of the function call in the RCX register.

I tested this under mingw gcc + jwasm and also VS 2015 and it works ok.

I'm not sure what I'm missing on Linux!

Comment: On Linux, 64-bit code uses the [x86-64 System V ABI](https://wiki.osdev.org/System_V_ABI#x86-64). The first 6 parameters are always passed via rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9 (in that order). The rest are pushed on the stack in right to left order. If you want to dump RCX you will have to move it to RDI before calling DumpRCX.

Comment: There is no shadow space on Linux either so you don't need to subtract 28h from RSP either. You will want to subtract 8 (or do a push like `push rbp`) to ensure 16 byte stack alignment before calling DumpRCX.

Answer (score 4):

**`__attribute__((ms_abi))`** should make your code do what you want.  It will tell gcc to use the Windows x64 calling convention for that function.  Or `sysv_abi` will use that calling convention for calls to that function (on platforms where that's not the default)

(But why would you do that?  Just pass the arg in RDI like normal for x86-64 System V, then the caller doesn't have to reserve shadow space.)

**`__attribute__((fastcall))` only does anything for i386 (`-m32`), not x86-64 targets.**

[The GCC manual's x86 function attributes page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html#x86-Function-Attributes) documents this pretty clearly: *On x86-32 targets, the fastcall attribute...*

---

You can put your code on https://godbolt.org/ or look at `gcc -O3 -S` output locally and see which register it's actually copying to `RSI` as the 2nd arg for `printf`.